# What happened to sqlite MvvmCross GetConnectionWithLock?

Tags: sqlite, cross-platform, mvvmcross

I cannot find a patch note anywhere as to why GetConnectionWithLock is removed from MvvmCross.

It is still listed in the [docs](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/sqlite-pcl) but not it no longer exists in the IMvxSqliteConnectionFactory in version 4.4.

Should I just switch to GetConnection now or GetAsyncConnection and should I manually use the lock(object)?

Answer (score 1):

We switched away from using the SQLite.Net-PCL library from Oystein Krogh to use Sqlite-net-pcl from Frank Kreuger, because the former does not seem to get any updates and abandoned by the author. The switch was mainly due to lacking Android N support.

However, we are removing the SQLite plugin in next release, since there is not much point in having a light wrapper which only registers the plugin.

Comment: Android N was the main reason I updated to this version, but on our shared code we retrieved the connection with "GetConnectionWithLock". I'm not sure what to replace it with now, seeing that it does not exist anymore. Is the locking process unnecessary now? I don't want to mess the ios project in the process.